# Ant Design - Vertical Group of Checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, jsx, antd

I am trying to make a column of checkboxes using Ant design. I have tried:

```
 <Checkbox.Group>
          <Checkbox>Hello</Checkbox>
          <Checkbox>Hello1</Checkbox>
          <Checkbox>Hello2</Checkbox>
</Checkbox.Group>
```

And:

```
<CheckboxGroup options={plainOptions} value={this.state.checkedList} onChange={this.onChange} />
```

However, there does not seem to be an option to make checkboxes appear in a column instead of a row. I know I can use flexbox, but I was hoping Ant design would have a builtin method for making checkboxes appear vertically (in a column) instead of appearing in a horizontal row.

Is there a simple solution for stacking the checkboxes vertically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Doesn't appear like it does since the `<label>`s it renders are `display: inline-block`. The simplest solution (other than rewriting the component) is to change `.ant-checkbox-group-item`'s attributes from (you can always wrap the `CheckBox` with another class name to apply selectively, instead of globally):

```
.ant-checkbox-group-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

to:

```
.ant-checkbox-group-item {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Which will make it appear like so:
[image]

Optionally, you can also add a `display: inline-block` attribute to `.ant-checkbox-group`'s styles.

Which will then make it appear like so:
[image]

---

Another solution is to create some reusable components and apply the above via the `style` property (admittedly, not an elegant solution since `CheckboxGroup`'s `onChange` function expects to handle `options`, but you'd have to intercept them in order to alter the `Checkbox`'s style property).

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/w0voxxxzm5

**Checkbox.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "antd";

export default ({ disabled, label, value, handleChange }) => (
  <Checkbox
    style={{ display: "block", marginLeft: 0 }}
    disabled={disabled || false}
    label={label}
    checked={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    {label}
  </Checkbox>
);
```

**CheckboxGroup.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";

export default ({ options, ...props }) => (
  <div
    className="ant-checkbox-group"
    style={{ display: "inline-block", marginRight: 10 }}
  >
    {options.map(label => (
      <Checkbox
        key={label}
        label={label}
        disabled={props.disabled}
        handleChange={props.handleChange}
        value={props[label]}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

**Form.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CheckboxGroup from "./CheckboxGroup";

const options1 = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"];
const options2 = ["Strawberry", "Grape", "Mango"];
const options3 = ["Kiwi", "Banana", "Cherry"];

export default class Form extends Component {
  state = {};

  handleChange = ({ target: { label, checked } }) =>
    this.setState({ [label]: checked });

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert(JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 4));
  };

  render = () => (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <CheckboxGroup
        {...this.state}
        options={options1}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <CheckboxGroup
        {...this.state}
        options={options2}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <CheckboxGroup
        {...this.state}
        options={options3}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
        disabled
      />
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        <button className="ant-btn ant-btn-primary" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 12):

you can do this, and the content in item is also aligned and right！

```
   .ant-checkbox-group {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this was always working (since the question is 2 years old), but it is possible to arrange the checkboxes within a group vertically without tweaking the styles by simply wrapping each of them in a `<Row>` component:

```
import { Checkbox, Row, Form } from 'antd';

function onChange(checkedValues) {
  console.log('checked = ', checkedValues);
}

const GoodFruitForm = () =>
  <Form>
    <Form.Item label="Good Fruit">
      <Checkbox.Group onChange={onChange}>
        <Row><Checkbox value='Apple'>Apple</Checkbox></Row>
        <Row><Checkbox value='Pear'>Pear</Checkbox></Row>
      </Checkbox.Group>
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
```

And the content renders as expected:

[image: Vertical Checkboxes]

Answer (score 3):

Following [Matt Carlotta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7376526/matt-carlotta) example if you are using a variant of styled component, you can achieve that with

```
export const ColumnCheckbox = styled(Checkbox.Group)`
.ant-checkbox-group-item {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
}
` 
<ColumnCheckbox options={['Hello','Hello1','Hello2']}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    return (
      <EnhanceSubContent title={TITLE}>
        <Alert
          className={styles.alertMargin}
          message="Select the Events below to receive notification."
          type="info"
          showIcon
        />
        <div className={styles.content}>
          <Checkbox.Group style={{ width: '100%' }} onChange={this.onChange}>
            <Row>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Space direction="vertical">
                  <Checkbox value="Link Up">Link Up</Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox value="Link Down">Link Down</Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox value="Power On">Power On</Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox value="Power Off">Power Off</Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox value="Cold Start">Cold Start</Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox value="Warm Start">Warm Start</Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox value="Port Link Up">Port Link Up</Checkbox>
                </Space>
              </Col>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Space direction="vertical">
                  <Checkbox value="Port Link Down">Port Link Down</Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox value="Authentication Failure">
                    Authentication Failure
                  </Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox value="Power1 ok">Power1 ok</Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox value="Power1 failure">Power1 failure</Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox value="Power2 ok">Power2 ok</Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox value="Power2 failure">Power2 failure</Checkbox>
                </Space>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Checkbox.Group>
          <Divider />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.buttonsContianer}>
          <Space align="end">
            <Button type="primary"> Apply </Button>
            <Button className={styles.cancelButton}> Reset </Button>
          </Space>
        </div>
      </EnhanceSubContent>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please refer the <div className={styles.content}> </div>, this will give you vertical checkbox group for two columns. You can increase/decrease the column count by adding or removing the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/), so you will not change `.ant-checkbox-group-item` style globally.

```
import { Checkbox } from 'antd';
import styled from 'styled-components'

const VerticalCheckboxGroup = styled(Checkbox.Group)`
  .ant-checkbox-group-item {
    display: block!important;
  }
`
```